# jQuery Mobile and Cordova not sending AJAX HTTP request multi-page model

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have searched this forum for answers and have tried different suggestions that worked for others but did not work for me - including adding the site address to the whitelist in `config.xml`.

I am working on developing a web app using HTML5, CSS and JavaScript with Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.6 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.3 for the UI. I am using a multi-page JQM page model with the need to make ajax request to submit forms to a server.

Testing the code on localhost works fine but when I build on Android platform in Cordova, the request is not even sent at all as I get the alert message I wrote for when the request is not sent ("Could not connect!").

The code is supposed to use the JSON object returned from the server to display the next page. My codes are as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("pageinit", function(){
                $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
                $.support.cors = true;
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <div data-role="page" id="login">
            <script>
                $(document).bind('mobileinit', '#login', function(){ 
                    $(function() {
                        $("#loginSubmit").on("click", function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://url-address.php",
                                type: "POST",
                                cache: false,                   
                                dataType: "json",           
                                data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),                          
                                success: function(result){
                                    if(result.status == "true")
                                    {
                                        alert('Login Successful!  ' + result.user);
                                        $.mobile.changePage("#play");
                                    }
                                    else if(result.status=="false")
                                    {
                                        alert('could not login');
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function(){
                                    alert('Could not connect!');                
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });         
            </script>
        </div>
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>App Login</h1>          
            </div>

            <div role="main" class="ui-content">        
                <h4>New account? <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a> now!</h4><hr>
                <form id="loginForm">
                    <label for="text-basic">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">

                    <label for="text-basic">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" id="loginSubmit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <a href="#forgotpwd"><strong>Forgot Password?</strong></a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!----------------- SECOND PAGE ---------------------->
        <div data-role="page" id="plan">
            <script>    
                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#plan' ,function() {
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    $('#gamebuttons').empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://url-address.php',          
                        dataType: 'json',
                        Cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {                           
                            $.each(data, function(i,item) {                     
                                $('#gamebuttons').append('<button type="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" name="plannumber" id="gamepanelbutton" value="'+item+'">' + item + '</button>');                                                   
                            });
                            $('#gamebuttons').refresh();                    
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            $('#gamebuttons').append('error importing data');               
                        }
                    });         
                });

                $(document).on("pageshow", "#plan", function(){     
                    $(function(){
                        $("#playSubmit").on("click", function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://url-address.php",
                                data: $("#play").serialize(),
                                type: "POST",
                                cache: false,
                                dataType: "json",           
                                data: {"am": am, "rl": rl},     
                                //data: {action: 'login', formData: $('#submitForm').serialize()},          
                                success: function(result){
                                    if(result.status == "true") {
                                        alert(result.message);
                                        //$.mobile.changePage("#play");
                                    } else if(result.status=="false") {
                                        alert(result.message);
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    alert('Could not send play request: Error executing request!');             
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <div data-role="header">            
                <h1>Main page</h1>
                <a href="#options" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-gear">Options</a>
                <a href="#help" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-info">Help</a>
            </div>
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>

                </p>

                <form id="play">
                    <!---the other form elements go here-->
                    <p>
                        <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-shadow" id="playSubmit">Play</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems ok. Try Chrome Remote Debugging and tell us what you see.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Let me try that and get back to you

Comment: Sorry the reply came late. I couldn't do anything after leaving work yesterday,but I'm back now. I've tried the Chrome Remote Debugging, I had never used it before anyway. It did not recognize my TECNO N9 PHANTOM TAB despite having 'USB Debugging' enabled in Developer Options. There seems to be no driver for it under the OEM Drivers list. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Did you connect it via USB, I assume so. Best I can say is to Google for it. I had issues with my M8 and had to find a random tip to get it recognized. Point is - once you get to where you can connect via Chrome, you should see the error a lot clearer. You can also try Weinre.

Comment: Yes I connected via USB, and I have Googled for it but did not get any USB driver for the N9. Let me try Weinre as you suggested and will feed you back. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You should clean up your code and take care about indentation. I edited your first post with good indent. You will see that there is a  that should not be here in your code, before the `<div data-role="header">` of your 1st page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("pageinit", function(){
                $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
                $.support.cors = true;
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <div data-role="page" id="login">
            <script>
                $(document).bind('mobileinit', '#login', function(){ 
                    $(function() {
                        $("#loginSubmit").on("click", function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://url-address.php",
                                type: "POST",
                                cache: false,                   
                                dataType: "json",           
                                data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),                          
                                success: function(result){
                                    if(result.status == "true")
                                    {
                                        alert('Login Successful!  ' + result.user);
                                        $.mobile.changePage("#play");
                                    }
                                    else if(result.status=="false")
                                    {
                                        alert('could not login');
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function(){
                                    alert('Could not connect!');                
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });         
            </script>

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>App Login</h1>          
            </div>

            <div role="main" class="ui-content">        
                <h4>New account? <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a> now!</h4><hr>
                <form id="loginForm">
                    <label for="text-basic">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">

                    <label for="text-basic">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" id="loginSubmit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <a href="#forgotpwd"><strong>Forgot Password?</strong></a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!----------------- SECOND PAGE ---------------------->
        <div data-role="page" id="plan">
            <script>    
                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#plan' ,function() {
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    $('#gamebuttons').empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://url-address.php',          
                        dataType: 'json',
                        Cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {                           
                            $.each(data, function(i,item) {                     
                                $('#gamebuttons').append('<button type="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" name="plannumber" id="gamepanelbutton" value="'+item+'">' + item + '</button>');                                                   
                            });
                            $('#gamebuttons').refresh();                    
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            $('#gamebuttons').append('error importing data');               
                        }
                    });         
                });

                $(document).on("pageshow", "#plan", function(){     
                    $(function(){
                        $("#playSubmit").on("click", function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://url-address.php",
                                data: $("#play").serialize(),
                                type: "POST",
                                cache: false,
                                dataType: "json",           
                                data: {"am": am, "rl": rl},     
                                //data: {action: 'login', formData: $('#submitForm').serialize()},          
                                success: function(result){
                                    if(result.status == "true") {
                                        alert(result.message);
                                        //$.mobile.changePage("#play");
                                    } else if(result.status=="false") {
                                        alert(result.message);
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    alert('Could not send play request: Error executing request!');             
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <div data-role="header">            
                <h1>Main page</h1>
                <a href="#options" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-gear">Options</a>
                <a href="#help" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-info">Help</a>
            </div>
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>

                </p>

                <form id="play">
                    <!---the other form elements go here-->
                    <p>
                        <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-shadow" id="playSubmit">Play</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For your request problem, have you changed the URL to map the real server mapping?

Comment: Yes I use the correct server URL. I only put this as a sample. Thanks, I will clean up the code

Comment: OK then try to get more info inside your error handler, like this `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}`

Comment: I have tried it, it is still not returning anything

Comment: Yes, no hanging div...html is okay